# Informatica PowerCenter - [ERROR] HTTP Invoker encountered an error while invoking the HTTP

Tags: http, informatica, azure-cognitive-search, informatica-powercenter

I need to send HTTP Transformation a JSON that it will send to Azure Search.

I've the following problem:

```
Message Code: PCHTTP_33016
Message: [ERROR] HTTP Invoker encountered an error while invoking the HTTP. Reason: {"error":{"code":"","message":"The request is invalid. Details: parameters : Invalid JSON. Unexpected end of input reached while processing a JSON string value.\r\n"}}
```

I'm trying to send the following JSON:

```
{"values": {"_Load_Timestamp": "2021-10-12 15:30:13.878228","_Load_RunId": "1","NUM_ORDI": "XXXXX450","TIP_MOVI": "X","COD_XXX": "XXX","NUM_XXX": "XXXXXXX4031","TIP_DOCU": "1","NUM_DOCT": "0","NUM_DOCD": "0","MOV_DTEF": "9999-12-31 23:59:59.000000","MOV_DTSC": null,"MOV_DTEM": "9999-12-31 23:59:59.000000","MOV_DTRG": "9999-12-31 23:59:59.000000","COD_TMOV": "1","COD_CAUS": "0","MES_LIMI": null,"DAT_ULCO": null,"NUM_ORDX": null,"NUM_MOVX": null,"TIP_RELA": null,"COD_PRVZ": "24","COD_USER": "XXXXX","DES_NOTE": null,"COD_STAT": "0","PRG_STAM": null,"SEQ_TITO": null,"FLG_AQTZ": null,"COD_GEST": null,"COD_USE1": null,"MOV_DTIT": null,"FLG_EMTI": null,"MOV_RETT": null,"FLG_VERI": "N","FLG_STMP": "N","TIP_POLI": "P","CAU_BLOC": null,"NOT_BLOC": null,"STA_AUTO": null,"IDN_AUTO": null,"PTN_AUTO": null,"DAT_INGA": "9999-12-31 23:59:59.000000","DAT_INCO": null,"WEB_COMP": "XXX","FNO_ANIA": null,"IDE_NAPC": null,"COD_CAPA": null,"DAT_PEDG": null,"DAT_OPER": null,"NUM_STMP": null,"FLG_BOZZ": null,"FLG_P021": null,"VAL_SPPO": null,"NUM_SPPO": null,"_UPDATE_DATE": "2021-10-12 12:51:13.878233","_CAPXACTION": "I"}}
```

I also checked the json in an online JSON validator and the syntax is valid. ([jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/))

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Please provide more details about what you are sending this JSON object to and how.

Comment: Have you validated the http api using swagger ? Is it working there?

Comment: Hi @BertrandLeRoy, 
I've an Expression transformation that has an output field that creates the JSON string.
This string will be passed as input into the HTTP transformation. 
In the HEADER of the HTTP transformation I pass the fields "api-key" and "Content-Type" with their respective values: 
Api-Key → Azure Search key 
Content-Type → 'application/json

Comment: Make sure the payload is not trucated. Your JSON is 1117 characters long, just check if the field used is not set to 1000, for example. And verify all the transformations across the flow.

Comment: Hi @Maciejg, I setted the length of json field to 4194304 bytes.

Comment: Create an endpoint on https://beeceptor.com/ and point your webservice call to that one, then verify if what it gets is looking as expected.

Comment: We still don't have enough details about what endpoint you're using, how the data is being sent, or the configuration used to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try removing the null values?

```
{
    "values": {
        "_Load_Timestamp": "2021-10-12 15:30:13.878228",
        "_Load_RunId": "1",
        "NUM_ORDI": "XXXXX450",
        "TIP_MOVI": "X",
        "COD_XXX": "XXX",
        "NUM_XXX": "XXXXXXX4031",
        "TIP_DOCU": "1",
        "NUM_DOCT": "0",
        "NUM_DOCD": "0",
        "MOV_DTEF": "9999-12-31 23:59:59.000000",
        "MOV_DTEM": "9999-12-31 23:59:59.000000",
        "MOV_DTRG": "9999-12-31 23:59:59.000000",
        "COD_TMOV": "1",
        "COD_CAUS": "0",
        "COD_PRVZ": "24",
        "COD_USER": "XXXXX",
        "COD_STAT": "0",
        "FLG_VERI": "N",
        "FLG_STMP": "N",
        "TIP_POLI": "P",
        "DAT_INGA": "9999-12-31 23:59:59.000000",
        "WEB_COMP": "XXX",
        "_UPDATE_DATE": "2021-10-12 12:51:13.878233",
        "_CAPXACTION": "I"
    }
}
```